# MongoDB: Actualizar el valor de dos o más campos de todos los documentos de una colección

Tags: mongodb, update

Dada una colección llamada `datasets` que contiene varios documentos como éste:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo podría hacer para actualizar el valor de dos (o más) campos de un `Object` determinado de `components` en todos los documentos de la colección?

En concreto, quiero que la `label` y el `fieldName` de valor `"co_gid"`, allí donde existan, pasen a tener un valor de `"co_int"`.

Mi aproximación, para un sólo elemento, sería ésta:

```
db.datasets.updateMany({"components.label": "co_gid"}, {$set: {"components.label": "co_int"}});
```

No sé si es correcta, pero además necesitaría que no sólo actualizase `label` en todos los documentos de la colección sino que además actualizase `fieldName`. ¿Se puede hacer de una sola vez -supongo que incluyendo un array en la consulta- o necesito a continuación dar otra orden tal que así?

```
db.datasets.updateMany({"components.fieldName": "co_gid"}, {$set: {"components.fieldName": "co_int"}});
```

Insisto en que no sé siquiera si esta orden es correcta... Estoy haciendo pruebas en un servidor de desarrollo y querría estar seguro antes de teclear nada...

Gracias por adelantado.

Comment: Hola Javier, lo que dices si que se puede hacer. A set le tienes que pasar los campos que quieres actualizar dentro de un diccionario. Cuando esté esn casa si no te han respondido ya, te pongo la manera de hacerlo, pero es practicanente igual a lo que has hecho. Lo que puedes hacer es crearte otra coleccion similar si quieres hacer pruebas, así no fastidias la original.

Comment: Sí, no te preocupes, estoy a punto de salir de trabajar así que me pondré a hacer las pruebas mañana.

Comment: Ok, debería ser algo así: db.datasets.updateMany({"components.label": "co_gid"}, {$set: {"components.label": "co_int", "components.fieldname": "co_int"}}). Pero ya te digo que estoy escribiendo de memoria y no he podido probarlo aún.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existen dos posibilidades según lo que quieras:

La primera (la más sencilla) es si una vez que detecte en el documento que existe un `components.label = co_gid` que automáticamente cambie todos los `components.label` y `components.fieldName` a `co_int`. Por ejemplo en el documento que has puesto, puesto que existe uno, cambiaría todos independientemente del valor que tengan. Creo que no es esto lo que buscas, pero por si no te he entendido bien, te pongo cómo sería:

```
df = db.datasets.update_many({'components.label': 'co_gid'},
                             {'$set': {
                                 "components.$[].label": "co_int",
                                 "components.$[].fieldName": "co_int"
                               }
                             })
```

Y la segunda posibilidad, que creo que es la que buscas, es que únicamente cambie a `co_int` los valores de `components.label` y `components.fieldName` que valgan `co_gid`, y eso se haría de la siguiente manera:

```
df = db.datasets.update_many({},
                             {'$set': {
                                 "components.$[c1].label": "co_int",
                                 "components.$[c2].fieldName": "co_int"
                             }},
                              upsert=False,
                              array_filters=[{'c1.label': 'co_gid'}, {'c2.fieldName': 'co_gid'}]
                             )
```

Yo lo he hecho con python (pymongo) si no es con este lenguaje con el que trabajas (ya que no tienes etiqueta de ninguno), deberás buscar como escribirlo, porque aunque será muy parecido, habrá ligeras diferencias.

**Código desde la Shell de Mongo**

Para hacerlo desde la Shell el código cambiaría un poquito, debería ser así:

```
db.datasets.updateMany(
   { },
   { $set: { "components.$[c1].label" : "co_int", "components.$[c2].fieldName" : "co_int" } },
   { 
     arrayFilters: [ { "c1.label": "co_gid" }, { "c2.fieldName": "co_gid" } ]
   }
)
```

Comment: Por lo que tenía entendido, el shell de Mongo es un intérprete de JS. No tengo ninguna otra biblioteca instalada, sólo las versiones más reciente de Compass y del shell.

Comment: Pymongo es un driver para utilizar mongodb con Python. Si lo haces a través de la shell de mongo sería ligeramente diferente. Es alguno de los dos casos que te he puesto lo que buscabas?

Comment: Sí, sí, la segunda posibilidad es la que busco, un cambio específico de `co_gid` a `co_int`; la primera me desgraciaría el dataset. Tengo Mongo instalado en local también, así que podría hacer ahí las pruebas; si peta podría recuperar la BD desde el servidor de desarrollo.

Comment: Te lo he puesto en una actualización, si tienes algún problema me dices.

Comment: Lo cierto es que la sintaxis de tu código parece coherente con mis objetivos, pero lo he probado en local y por lo que veo en Compass sólo me ha funcionado para `label`; `fieldname` sigue con valor `"co_gid"`. La respuesta que me ha dado el CMD es la siguiente: `{ "acknowledged" : true, "matchedCount" : 16, "modifiedCount" : 2 }`. Tengo 16 datasets y sólo 2 (en esta base de datos local) tienen el elemento "co_gid"; supongo que se refiere a eso y no a que haya modificado únicamente las 2 `label`.

Comment: Ahí se refiere al número de documentos que coinciden con el criterio de búsqueda, en este caso al poner {} te salen todos, y te dice también la cantidad de ellos que ha modificado (haya hecho un cambio o más). Puedes insertar otro documento con co_gid y verás que ahora solo te pondrá que ha modificado uno (los otros ya deberían tener co_int).

Comment: He partido la orden en dos: `db.datasets.updateMany({}, {$set: {"components.$[c1].label": "co_int"}}, {arrayFilters: [{"c1.label": "co_gid"}]})` funciona pero `db.datasets.updateMany({}, {$set: {"components.$[c1].fieldname": "co_int"}}, {arrayFilters: [{"c1.fieldname": "co_gid"}]})` no. ¿Se te ocurre por qué puede ser?

Comment: Vale, el problema era que no es `fieldname` sino `fieldName`.

Comment: Tienes toda la razón, viene en la imagen que has puesto, y lo he puesto yo mal, voy a modificar la respuesta para que esté bien puesto

Comment: Entiendo que para modificar más `components` simplemente tengo que ir añadiéndolos al `$set` y al `arrayFilters`, tal que así: `db.datasets.updateMany({}, {$set: {"components.$[c1].label": "co_int", "components.$[c2].fieldName": "co_int", "components.$[c3].label": "co_queue", "components.$[c4].fieldName": "co_queue"}}, {arrayFilters: [{"c1.label": "co_gid"}, {"c2.fieldName": "co_gid"}, {"c3.label": "co_sfid"}, {"c4.fieldName": "co_sfid"}]})`

Comment: No se si ya lo habrás probado, pero efectivamente es así

Comment: Sí, ya estoy tuneando la BD a mi antojo. Muchas gracias, Adrián.